# Two tags for the 18th century

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging, tag-synonyms

At the moment, we have tag [18c](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/18c) and tag [18th-century](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/18th-century). Would it be wise to merge them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unclear to me whether century tags are useful at all, but in any case we certainly don't need two for the same time period. I merged [18c](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/18c) into [18th-century](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/18th-century).